# Alias for chained API calls?

Tags: api, chaining

I have a query in which I need to chain `api.Contact.getsingle` twice, given that the entity I'm querying is linked to two different contacts for which I need to fetch the data.

The problem is that, given that both chained calls have the same name, it seems that the last one overrides the first.

Basically I need to do this:

`$result = civicrm_api3('MyEntity', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'api.Contact.getsingle' => array('id' => "\$value.contact_id"),
  'api.Contact.getsingle' => array('id' => "\$value.manager_id"),
));`

but with the ability to "alias" each chained call so that they don't get overridden

Is it possible to do it? If not, what a different approach would look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a notation for issuing multiple chains by appending ".2", ".3", etc. For example, in [api/v3/examples/Contact/ChainTwoWebsites.php](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.2/api/v3/examples/Contact/ChainTwoWebsites.php), it uses:

```
'api.website.create' => array(
  'url' => 'http://civicrm.org',
),
'api.website.create.2' => array(
  'url' => 'http://chained.org',
),
```

As far as I know, there is no way to do aliases.

Note: The class which handles chaining is [ChainSubscriber](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.2/Civi/API/Subscriber/ChainSubscriber.php). In skimming that code, I don't see anything which explicitly processes the ".2" suffix as a number. It would be worth a try to use a prettier/symbolic suffix (e.g. `api.Contact.getsingle.self`, `api.Contact.getsingle.manager`) -